# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'daq' from R reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

### Goal

I want to use [`undaqTools`](https://pythonhosted.org/undaqTools/) module via `reticulate` in R.

### Reproducible example

I first installed python (version 3.10), created a virtual env, and installed all dependencies including `undaqTools`:

```
library(reticulate)
path_to_python <- install_python()
virtualenv_create("undaq_env", python = path_to_python)


py_install(packages = c("scipy", "numpy", "matplotlib", "h5py",
                        "nose", "sphinx", "numpydoc", "undaqTools",
                        "dask", "dask[dataframe]", "pyarrow",
                        "storefact"),
           envname = "undaq_env")
```

Then I activated the virtual environment:

```
use_virtualenv("undaq_env")
```

But when I try to import `undaqTools`, it throws an error:

```
undaqtools <- import("undaqTools")

# Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
#   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'daq'
```

You can see that `daq` is available though:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You're probably not including daq right. Try to use `from undaqTools import daq`. Tihs should work.

~coderwindows03

Comment: The code in `undaqTools` module is not written by me. I tried `undaqTools` in python 2.7 and it successfully imported. But I get the above error in python 3.10 with or without `reticulate` in R. Probably, the module works for python 2.7 only.

Comment: i guess so, the latest version is from 2013 and on the [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/undaqTools/0.2.3/) page it explicitly says that it's for python 2.7. What about using numpy or pandas ? these modules are constantly updated so they should work flawlessly

Comment: The other modules work on python 3.10. There was an update on the github of `undaqTools` 13 months ago, so I thought it may be updated for python 3. Thanks for pointing out the pypi info.

Comment: So in a sense - you weren't importing daq right... you had to use python 2.7 and not 3.x to import.